# How do I workout the Poisson equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, differential, poissons-equation

I have trouble with working out the Poisson equation. I don't know how to go from step $1$ to step $2$.  Why is in $(2.)$ the $k$ in front of the nabla sign? How did the nabla sign come in front of the $k$ (in the bracketed part.)

$$\begin{array}{l}
 (1.) -\nabla \cdot(k \nabla u)=f \\
 (2.) -k \nabla \cdot \nabla u-(\nabla k) \cdot(\nabla u)=f
\end{array}$$

It would be great if someone can give me a hint.

Ter

Comment: Looks like the product rule? $$\nabla \cdot f\vec{v}=(\nabla f)\cdot \vec{v} + f\nabla\cdot\vec{v}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of notation. For three variables, we write

- $\nabla u = (u_x,u_y,u_z)$
- $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_y,\partial_z)$

Then,
$$\begin{aligned}\nabla\cdot(k\nabla u)&= (\partial_x, \partial_y,\partial_z)\cdot(ku_x,ku_y,ku_z)\\
&=\partial_x(k u_x)+\partial_y(ku_y)+\partial_z(ku_z)
\end{aligned}$$